# Parser Mismatched Metadata error

Tags: facebook, parsing, metadata

I get this error message when i use URL Linter with my website
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=iulianonofrei.com
And I have this header:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Onofrei Iulian Photography" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Onofrei Iulian's photography portfolio." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://iulianonofrei.com/images/favicon_1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://iulianonofrei.com/images/macro/panorama_3_t.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://iulianonofrei.com" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Onofrei Iulian Photography" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="_" />
```

I can't figure out why I get that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an error but warning message which may be ignored as long as the details you get from Link Debugger are correct.

You may try to play with an order of OpenGraph meta tags by moving `og:url` before `og:image` (there is no "correct" order documented for that)...

BTW, The warning message however is weird. For same code (except for `og:url`) I get no warning messages at all. So it may be a good to [file a bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create).

Comment: But when i try to share a link on fb it shows only my first (favionc_1.jpg) image and not the second one too so it's not just about the warning

Comment: @RevoltEr, this isn't because of warning but due to manner Facebook is using images from OpenGraph properties. Second image is not conform the 3:1 ration. See my [detailed answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/10224461/155033) on subject.

Comment: I think i have this problem because of my redirect I use: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^iulianonofrei.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://iulianonofrei.com/$1 [L,R=301]` that eliminates "www" from the url

Comment: @RevoltEr, this have nothing to do with redirect ;)